# 1 table with 2 same foreign keys to 3rd table with Primary Key

Tags: join, ms-access

First time building a database in Access. I've been searching, but I did not find something to solve my question, so I finally decided to ask.

It may be a really stupid question but what is the best way to format something like the following:

One service is provided to two different recipients (table 1). These recipients are located in a recipient registry (table 2).

What is the best way to join both tables? Shall I create 2 tables: `PrimaryRecipient` and `SecondaryRecipient`?  Or a join table with the combination of recipients?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What would adding extra join tables accomplish?

Comment: You have 2 separate referencing fields - so you must join 2 separate copies of  referenced table.

Comment: Sounds like your design is off from the start: what if there's a tertiary recipient? You probably want a many-to-many relationship with a junction table (e.g. a table services listing all services, a table recipients listing all recipients, and a table servicerecipients with 1 row for each service-recipient combination).